# What is good way to obtain data for a travel application

Tags: java, android, xml, database, location

I have ran into a small issue with an Android App that I am currently working on. 
I have a list of points of interest declared in an XML file. The POI's look like this:

```
    <hotel>
    <name>Hotel Atlas</name>
    <latitude>45.612079</latitude>
    <longitude>25.660756</longitude>
    <thumb_url>/hotels/atlas.jpg</thumb_url>
    <phone>039999999</phone>
    </hotel>
```

The problem that I have is that there are about 200 points of interest and every time the users access the app the XML is read every time from an online location and that means high volumes of internet traffic. The XML is stored online so I can update it every time I want to add another POI and not force users to update the app. Is there any way to send this data to the app and not require to download the entire XML?

I have not yet found an optimum sollution for this and decided to ask for some opinions.

Thanks, Vlad

Comment: you can store them locally and update them once per while

Comment: I am trying to avoid storing locally, I was thinking of somehow getting just the new items, but in order to search for them in the XML, i need to read the entire XML file so the traffic still counts.

Comment: you can gets only POIs in some distance from user

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 possible ways:

1. Either give static database with all POI or
2. Load data from web whenever required.

Now you can do one thing, keep static database with App. Make web call once app starts and check for the updated data if any changes you made in server database. If there is any change on server database, then update only those data to the local(static) database.

For implementing above step, you must have to pass **Last Updated date** to/from server. I mean whenever you make web call, you need to pass last updated date from the client, server will check for new data to be updated post this date. Server will store client date as updated date and return back to client.

Comment: I recommend using the SQLite database that Android gives you @VladN

Comment: But if I use SQLite, is there a way of syncing the data from my the local database to a ( for example ) online MySql database?

Comment: @VladN my mean of Static/local database is SQLite database itself ;)

Comment: @VladN I told you the way of syncing database. At one point you are saying you want to update/change data frequently on web and at one point you are saying you want to sync local database to web database. Could you come at one point?

Comment: @PareshMayani I did not mean sync ... I was thinking of update. Your solution is a really good one, what I need to understand is this: The server database needs to be SQLite in order to get the updates or I can use another type of database ( mysql for example ).

Comment: @VladN one more thing, for syncing data between databases you must have WebService. If you have it then you don't need to worry about database type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to store POIs like "One POI - One file"? In this case you can easily read only new points from server